# Can I use shingles from lattice in ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, lattice

It is possible to use the `shingles` to define specific ranges in `ggplot2`.  As far as i understand `shingles` are a way to generate groups.  Can we create such `shingle`s and use them in `ggplot2` `facet_grid` to obtain graphs?

Comment: Shingles are a bit more than "defining groups". They are overlapping ranges of the conditioning variable, hence the term "shingle". If there isn't a shingle concept in ggplot2 then I don't think you can do what you propose for the reason that an individual sample can be in two "groups" where the ranges for two shingles overlap.

Comment: @Gavin, I agree with you.  But so far I have seen that ggplot2 pretty much replaces lattice, and does seem to be easier to use.  I just want to know if it is actually possible to do what you say, "an individual sample can be in two groups where ranges of two shingles overlap"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following up from the comments, `ggplot` can't draw shingles (in the way lattice draws shingles with special indicators in the strip) and by default doesn't have a means of producing the overlapping groups.

However, I cam across this excellent [PDF](http://learnr.files.wordpress.com/2009/08/latbook_time1.pdf) document which aims to produce a gpplot2 version of every figure in Depayan's excellent Lattice book ([Lattice: Multivariate Data Visualization with R](http://www.springer.com/statistics/computanional+statistics/book/978-0-387-75968-5?changeHeader)).

Page 31 contains a custom function `fn()` which replicates the behaviour of `equal.count()`, as far as I can tell, to provide the correct data structure to plot with overlapping shingles. The PDF contains plenty of examples of "shingles" in ggplot that you can play with.

So not sure if this answers the Q - but at least it appears one can fudge ggplot into producing plots that use the shingle concept.