# How to deal with overlapping factor levels? (e.g. when producing tables and plots)

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, r-factor

I am facing a problem with a dataset which has **overlapping factor levels**.

I would like to **produce timelines, barplots and statistics by factor level** - however, I want the factor levels to be equivocal. 
That means that observations belonging to more than one level should appear several times in a plot.

Here is an example of how my data structure looks like:

```
head <- c("ID","YEAR","BRAZIL","GERMANY","US","FRANCE")
data <- data.frame(matrix(c(1,2000,1,0,0,0,
                            2,2010,0,1,1,0,
                            3,2011,0,1,0,0,
                            4,2012,1,0,0,1,
                            5,2012,0,1,0,0,
                            6,2013,0,0,0,1), 
                         nrow=6, ncol=6, byrow=T))
names(data) <- head
```

Obiously, a possible factor variable `"COUNTRY"` cannot be created the usual way. It would force factor levels to be clear-cut (in our case there would be 4 levels: *Brazil, Germany, US* and *France*):

```
data$COUNTRY[data$BRAZIL==1 & 
             data$GERMANY==0 & 
             data$US==0 & 
             data$FRANCE==0]  <- "Brazil"
data$COUNTRY[data$BRAZIL==0 & 
             data$GERMANY==1 & 
             data$US==0 & 
             data$FRANCE==0]  <- "Germany"
```

etc...

```
factor(data$COUNTRY)
```

But this is not what, I want...

---

My problem is that plotting by factor only works if factor levels are properly unambiguous. 
I would like to produce something like this:

```
require(ggplot2)
MYPLOT <- qplot(data$YEAR, data$COUNTRY)
MYPLOT + geom_point(aes(size=..count..), stat="bin") + scale_size(range=c(0, 15))
```

with observations belonging to *i* factor levels to appear *i* times in the plot.

- How should I transform my data.frame in order to get what I desire?
- Should I simply duplicate those observations belonging to *i* factor levels *i* times? If yes, how should I do that?
- Is a workaround which does not require case duplications?

**Ideas anyone?**

Comment: Use `stat='identity'` in your plot call.  If that isn't it, please clarify as to how you're determining the `COUNTRY` column as it is completely unclear to me.

Comment: I edited my question. It should be clear now what I meant with a possible factor variable `COUNTRY`. `stat='identity'` is not what I want, I want `stat='bin'`.

Comment: for what it's worth, the `lattice` package has a concept/object type called *shingles*, which are explicitly designed for implementing overlapping classes (this is one of the cool features of lattice that didn't make it into ggplot): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199128/can-i-use-shingles-from-lattice-in-ggplot2-in-r

Comment: mh, *shingle* looks interesting, but it seems it would only accept numeric variables (or at least ordinal scale). However, my `COUNTRY' variable can only be measured on a nominal scale and is therefore not apt for *shingle.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to duplicate those rows to represent each observation. and remove any with 0.

```
library(reshape2)
d2<-melt(data, id.var=c("ID","YEAR"))
d3<-d2[d2$value!=0,]
library(ggplot2)
qplot(d3$YEAR, d3$variable)
```