# Function for Multilabel Formatting of Factor Categories in R

Tags: r, function, sas, categorical-data

## Problem

In some health datasets, a column may categorize various disease manifestations of interest for individual cases. In some summaries it is beneficial to tabulate various combinations of these manifestations, including counting if a given case had 'greater than' or 'less than' a selection of key manifestations.

In SAS, a column can be assigned a [`multilabel` format](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2016/12/16/creating-and-using-multilabel-formats/), which can allow various overlapping categories to be summarized at the same time during `procedure steps`. I have struggled to find a satisfactory solution in R that replicates this feature from SAS. I am aware that a combination of `dplyr` or `base` functions chained together can tabulate and append different combinations, effectively creating a dataset that duplicates rows needed for representing all [overlapping levels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21391562/4481570).

## Aim

To create a function that allows for easy creation of a dataset that considers various overlapping levels of a target category. This would allow for the transformation of the example data provided below into a new dataset that appends the correct rows, and can provide checks within groups to see if a certain grouping matches all the desired levels to be considered part of a new grouping.

```r
library(tibble)

# Example data (Repeat groups)
exampleData <- tibble(group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3),
                   condition = factor(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'Q'), ordered = F))

# Initial output
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  group condition
  <dbl> <fct>    
1     1 A        
2     1 B        
3     1 C        
4     2 A        
5     3 B        
6     3 Q  


# Function to add new level combinations, based upon the levels within each group.
create_multilevelFactor(exampleData , target_col = 'condition', group_col = 'group', new_levels = list('AB' = c('A', 'B'), 'QB' = c('Q', 'B')))

# Desired output
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  group condition track_col
  <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>
1     1 A                 1
2     1 B                 1
3     1 C                 1
4     2 A                 1
5     3 B                 1
6     3 Q                 1
7     1 AB                2
8     3 QB                3
```

You will note that the original factor levels persist, and the groups that contained the correct levels in the named list will form a new row if the combination exists. In more realistic examples, the grouping for *AB* could be considered as *group 1* having 'at least A or B disease manifestations'.

## Challenge

I suspect that others may have a similar need for this function and like me, are either ignorant of a simpler approach or have not come across an existing solution that is easy to use. During my thought process for this question, **I have created a function** (trying to use `base` R primarily) that, albeit inelegantly, creates the aforementioned desired output.

It is my **hope that others can provide a more ideal solution** using an alternative approach or increase robustness and wider applicability of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function provides a working, albeit inelegant, solution to the problem. I tend to overthink processes, which is likely reflected in the answer here.

This function will take in the initial dataset, and based upon if a grouping function is provided, it will create a new dataset with additional rows for various combinations of aggregated factor levels if those levels existed within the groupings.  Various new levels can be provided as a list, and an additional column makes it easy to see which new levels were added in addition to the original rows.

```r
#-----------------------------------------------------------#
# Create function for multilevel labelling of factor groups #
#-----------------------------------------------------------#
# target_col is a character string for the column of interest to be adjusted
# group_col is a character string for the column to check levels that exist within groupings
# new_levels is a list that uses name and value pairs to determine how new levels should be aggregated
# collapse will ensure that only unique combinations of the new level is appended
# track will add a flag to ensure one can easily see the new combinations that were appended
create_multilevelFactor <- function(data, target_col, new_levels , group_col, collapse = T, track = T) {
  #
  #  Do some basic checks on inputs
  #

  # Check if new_levels is provided as a list
  if(!is.list(new_levels)) stop('The provided set of levels is not in a list format, please provide as a list') 

  # Check if target_col is a factor
  if(!is.factor(data[[target_col]])) stop('The target column for multiple levels is not a factor, convert to a factor before proceeding.')

  # Check if levels are in list
  for(i in 1:length(new_levels)) {
    if(length(setdiff(levels(factor(new_levels[[i]])),
                      levels(factor(data[[target_col]])))) > 0) { # If levels in provided list contain a level not in the column, then throw error
      stop('Levels in list do not match the levels in the target column')
    }
  }

  # State if grouping col was provided and its purpose
  if(!missing(group_col)) { message(paste0('The following column is used as a grouping variable for summarizing multilevel factoring: ',
                                         group_col, '. If you do not want labels determined by those within groupings, leave argument blank.'))
    }

  #
  # Main 
  #

  # Set new column for tracking if desired
  if(track == T) {track_col <- rep(NA,nrow(data)); data$track_col <- 1;  trackColIndex <- 1;}

  OutData <- as.data.frame(NULL) # Empy data frame to fill and append later

  # Loop for all new levels of interest to add
  for(i in 1:length(new_levels)){

    tempData <- data # Look at fresh data every pass

    levelIndex <- which(levels(tempData[[target_col]]) %in% new_levels [[i]]) # Index of matches

    # If grouping provided, do necessary splits and rbinds
    if(!missing(group_col)) {
      tempData <- split(tempData, tempData[[group_col]]) # Split if there are groupings

      tempData <- lapply(tempData, function(x) {
        if(!(length(setdiff(levels(factor(new_levels [[i]])), levels(factor(x[[target_col]])))) > 0)) { # If the grouping does not have all the levels for the new grouping, then do nothing
          levels(x[[target_col]])[levelIndex] <- names(new_levels )[i]
          x
          }
        })

      tempData <- do.call(rbind, tempData)  # If didnt match necessary group conditions, will bring back empty
      rownames(tempData) <- NULL # Correct row names for tibble

    } else { # If not grouping
      levels(tempData[[target_col]])[levelIndex] <- names(new_levels )[i]

      }

    tempData <- tempData[tempData[[target_col]] %in% names(new_levels )[i],] # Only keep new factor levels (could be empty if no group matches)

    if(collapse == T) tempData <- unique(tempData[(tempData[[target_col]] %in% names(new_levels )[i]),]) # Collapse to unique combinations if desired

    if(track == T){track_col <- rep(NA, nrow(tempData));  tempData$track_col <- trackColIndex+1;  trackColIndex <- trackColIndex+1;} # Add track column to the new rows

    OutData <- suppressWarnings(dplyr::bind_rows(OutData, tempData)) # Append all the new rows
    }

  # Append new rows to the original rows
  OutData <- suppressWarnings(dplyr::bind_rows(data, OutData)) #

  return(OutData)

}
```

Using the example data initially provided, this can produce the following outputs:

```r
#Original data
library(tibble)

# Example data (Repeat groups)
exampleData <- tibble(group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3),
                   condition = factor(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'Q'), ordered = F))

# Original data
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  group condition
  <dbl> <fct>    
1     1 A        
2     1 B        
3     1 C        
4     2 A        
5     3 B        
6     3 Q 

##################

newData <- create_multilevelFactor(exampleData,
                        target_col = 'condition',
                        group_col = 'group',
                        new_levels = list('AB' = c('A', 'B'), 'QB' = c('Q', 'B')),
                        collapse = T, track = T)

newData 
# Data with grouping argument
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  group condition track_col
  <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>
1     1 A                 1
2     1 B                 1
3     1 C                 1
4     2 A                 1
5     3 B                 1
6     3 Q                 1
7     1 AB                2
8     3 QB                3

addmargins(table(newData$group,newData$condition))
      A AB B C Q QB Sum
  1   1  1 1 1 0  0   4
  2   1  0 0 0 0  0   1
  3   0  0 1 0 1  1   3
  Sum 2  1 2 1 1  1   8

newData <- create_multilevelFactor(exampleData,
                        target_col = 'condition',
                        new_levels = list('AB' = c('A', 'B'), 'QB' = c('Q', 'B')),
                        collapse = T, track = T)

newData 
# Without grouping argument
# A tibble: 11 x 3
   group condition track_col
   <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>
 1     1 A                 1
 2     1 B                 1
 3     1 C                 1
 4     2 A                 1
 5     3 B                 1
 6     3 Q                 1
 7     1 AB                2
 8     2 AB                2
 9     3 AB                2
10     1 QB                3
11     3 QB                3

newData <- create_multilevelFactor(exampleData,
                        target_col = 'condition',
                        new_levels = list('AB' = c('A', 'B'), 'QB' = c('Q', 'B')),
                        collapse = F, track = T)

newData 
# Without collapse and grouping argument
# A tibble: 13 x 3
   group condition track_col
   <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>
 1     1 A                 1
 2     1 B                 1
 3     1 C                 1
 4     2 A                 1
 5     3 B                 1
 6     3 Q                 1
 7     1 AB                2
 8     1 AB                2
 9     2 AB                2
10     3 AB                2
11     1 QB                3
12     3 QB                3
13     3 QB                3
```